# Should I use a tag for my online course?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I plan to publish an online course and SO would be a great place for questions.

Can I use a tag for questions in this context, such as "julios-amazing-course", along with other tags related to that content?

I'd like to answer all student's questions on the class content, but not all questions about that subject. I can and would like to answer other people questions, but I need to make sure I will answer all questions from the course students. I thought tags would be a simple way to do this and I believe this would be an acceptable and welcome use of Stack Exchange. Please let me know if this assumptions are wrong.

Comment: I was answered and understood why my assumptions were wrong, but would like to understand why this question was so voted down. Why was that a bad question?

Comment: Seems like *some* people thought it was a feature-request or suchlike, instead of a well-written support-request asking for clarification and elaboration on site-policy. Such happens, though don't worry: There's no adverse effect to being downvoted on meta.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/meta-tags/info

Comment: Hi @Julio_AWS_DevRel!  Funny - i was just about to ask the same question! :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using tags (or any other part of the Q&A system) to mark questions as related to someone's course, or book, or event is generally not appropriate on Stack Overflow, and will only lead to trouble.

You'd need to find a different way to keep track of questions related to your course.

If it were my course, though, I would not do this on Stack Overflow in the first place.

I'd be too afraid of students running into trouble with the SO community, especially if they are novices to programming.

You would have to make super sure they all know how to ask good-quality, well-formulated, on-topic questions that aren't duplicates to prevent them from having a bad experience.

That may be too much to ask for many.

I would consider setting up a custom forum instead, created specifically for interacting with students, and answering their questions in a protected space.

A simple phpBB-like Open Source forum - or maybe a copy of [Discourse](http://discourse.org)! -  should work much better than outsourcing this to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yup, yup. In a nutshell your great recommendation is: Don't throw your students to the lions. Never heard of Discourse and am intrigued. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Thank you, your answer that makes it very clear.

Comment: There is at least one precedent for this, however: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cs193p which was discussed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155585/do-we-need-a-cs193p-tag-on-so . That tag was created organically, and the community decided to keep it once it had become popular.

Answer (score 11):

No, such tags say nothing about the problem people following your course would be facing; it'd be a [meta tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/meta-tags/info) instead.

People asking questions should just tag with the appropriate tags that actually cover the *problem they are facing*. Where that problem originated is of no concern and won't help attract experts on the subject matter.

As such, you'll have to find other ways to find how people are asking questions related to your course. Perhaps doing periodic searches for key words from your sample source, as well as your course or site name would help there (sometimes people name the tutorial they are following in the question body itself, which is fine if relevant).

Generally, we ask that people posting questions have done their research first and include a proper show of effort, as well as enough detail about the problems they are actually facing. Past experience has shown that a lot of programming novices (the people your course might be aimed at) fail at meeting these strict quality standards and end up having a rather disappointing experience with the site. As such, you may want to be careful when recommending Stack Overflow as a place to get help with your course.

Comment: I *think* his Q is related to using SO for QA related to his course; ie a 3rd Party type thing.  YMMV

Comment: I believe i made the problem a bit more clear in the update above.

Comment: @Plutonix: ah, yes, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an interesting use case for the relatively new [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) feature. It "is a private, secure home for your team’s questions and answers." In this case, the "team" could consist of yourself, current students, any other instructors, and possibly course graduates who could stick around if they wanted to contribute further. Teams seems to be primarily *marketed* toward businesses, but there doesn't seem to be  a reason why it *wouldn't* work for a class or school. The main issue is that Teams *costs money*. Depending on how much you have available in your course budget, it might be worth it. It would certainly beat having your students come onto the main site and get downvoted, deleted, and question banned for posting too broad, vague, or course-specific content not favored by the rest of the Stack Overflow community.

I have no affiliation with Stack Overflow for Teams other than being a (regular) Stack Overflow user.

Comment: Sounds awesome, thanks! Not for an open course thou unfortunatelly...