# Is it a correct use of tags in Stack Overflow by creating my own for my own tutorial website?

Tags: support, tags

I notice that [Harvard CS50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS50) has a tag on Stack Overflow.

I then checked out this piece about any limitations on creating new tags: *[Privileges - Create new tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)*

And it says that:

> on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.

### Use case 1

Let's pretend I create my own community website called `learnweb` writing tutorials of a certain piece of technology, let's say, Python.

And I want to send all questions to Stack Overflow. So I create a new tag called `[learnweb]`.

Is this use case okay? What limitations are there? Are there any triggers for culling in Stack Overflow?

### Use case 2

Another use case is I create my own open source project `dosomething` and host on GitHub.

I direct questions of usage to Stack Overflow and only allow bugs and feature requests as GitHub issues. Therefore I create a new tag in Stack Overflow called `dosomething`.

Same questions as per the previous use case.

Is this use case okay? What limitations? Any triggers for culling?

If one use case is okay, and another one is not, what's the rule that makes this distinction?

Comment: Re Use case 1: No, it's not. See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280906/11682469). I'm not sure about Use case 2 though "feature requests" look off topic, you need to be more specific about what kind of project it is. In general, see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/11682469).

Comment: You have to ensure that users know which questions they can ask on SO. Just telling people on GitHub to ask on SO often ends in tears. Also note, that tags should be created when there are already some questions that can be tagged with it. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944

Comment: ah... okay I get it now. Thank you. Sounds like the cs50 tag happened organically after sufficient people ask about the homework stuff there.

Comment: The usage guidance of [tag:cs50] reads: "For code using cs50.h or Python cs50 library, the libraries used in Harvard's self-study introductory computer science course named CS50. It is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to additionally tag with C and Python."

Comment: I saw that. Thank you @JeanneDark. I have the answers I'm looking for

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Answer (score 2):

This comment [Should I use a tag for my online course?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280904/should-i-use-a-tag-for-my-online-course/280906#comment132774_280906) suggests that learning community tags happen organically after sufficient people pose questions without that tag.

So use case 1 is not valid if deliberately planned. See [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280906/11682469) as per Jeanne Dark's comment.

As for use case 2, while not exactly invalid, it's not exactly a great idea to tell people on GitHub to ask questions on SO. Though that can still work similar to use case 1 once there's an organic pool of questions about the piece of open source tech.

Comment: "learning community tags" if you refer to [tag:cs50] that's not what that tag is about. It's about the *library* they use in that course, not the course itself.

Comment: many companies write that they are also present to answer questions in SO. but i am asking myself, if w3schools has a tag? no rurorial sites haven't their own tags, but they are mention for their shortcommings

Comment: @nbk is there a w3schools tag?

Comment: no there is no such a tag, that why then user shouldn't also add  such a tag, besides such tutorial sides are missing a peer review, like here, so that bugs and samples could be fixed, look at he hundreds of youtube videos with huge security bugs, comment that say that are deleted#