# Etiquette of creating a tag for my own software

Tags: discussion, support, self-promotion, tag-creation-process

I am the author of a scientific software package, about which people occasionally ask questions on Stack Overflow. I would like to create a tag for this, so I have an easy way to get directly informed about any new question.

Technically, there is no problem: I have the reputation to create the tag and add it to existing questions. However, as I am the author of the software in question, this has a whiff of abusing my privileges and self-advertisement. As tags are not owned by anybody, I cannot disclose my affiliation. How should I best go about this:

- Should I just go ahead and create the tag?
- Should I first put it for discussion on meta?
- Something else?

Some notes:

- I do not direct people to Stack Overflow as a dedicated support channel; that would be GitHub.
- The software is free, but I indirectly benefit from citations.
- [Is it a correct use of tags in Stack Overflow by creating my own for my own tutorial website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400921/2127008) covers the cases of creating a tag for a website and directing people to SO for one’s software, but not creating a tag for one’s software.
- [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/) doesn’t address the topic at all and there is no reason to assume it was considered.  I’d rather clarify this before I do something rather than setting a precedent that sparks controversy afterwards.

Comment: I'd argue that if other people have started asking about it, there's not really a grey area (assuming it's on-topic, which it is in this case) -- just make it. If people are asking about it organically, someone somewhere will eventually make a tag for it anyway. That might as well be you now when there's relatively few posts (I read "occasionally" as an implication of "few" in this context) to add the tag to after the fact, rather than later when there's more. The obligatory disclaimers when answering probably still apply when you answer, but making a tag isn't really a problem.

Comment: Just make sure that if you decide to write an excerpt/wiki for the tag it's impartial/no adspeak/etc. but conflicts of interest aren't really relevant for creating the tag itself, just put in some extra effort to make sure it's on-topic and questions you tag are really about this product and don't happen to be using it in the code while it's not directly relevant for the question.

Comment: @yivi: I have, and unless I completely missed something, it doesn’t address this topic at all – to the extent that I didn’t even deem it worth mentioning here.

Comment: It does, in the sense that the rules for tag creation are what they are. Self promotion does not enter into the equation. _"if you think there is a clear need for a tag, go ahead and create it yourself"_. Or _"alternatively, you can request the creation of a tag by starting a new meta discussion. This gives other people the opportunity to discuss if the new tag is needed"_ There is no need for a specific reasoning regards this specific case, because the general guidance suffices.

Comment: @yivi: There is no indication that the general guidance was written with this exceptional case in mind. Like almost everywhere in life, assuming that something obviously extraordinary is allowed, **only** because it is not explicitly forbidden, is not ethical behaviour. I’d rather have this clearly settled before I do something rather than negotiating a messy precedent after it happened.

Comment: Well, I disagree. I don't think the situation is particularly exceptional. Maintainers are often tag creators. There is nothing self-promotional in creating a tag itself, as long as the tag is good. If in doubt, post a question about the specific you want to create. Good luck, bye!